# Get separate text in same line BS4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Using beautiful soup, how do I get the team names and the points in different lists from the following list:

```
[<div class="name">Man. City<span class="record">19 pts</span></div>,
 <div class="name">Liverpool<span class="record">19 pts</span></div>,
 <div class="name">Chelsea<span class="record">17 pts</span></div>,
 <div class="name">Tottenham<span class="record">18 pts</span></div>,
 <div class="name">Arsenal<span class="record">18 pts</span></div>,
 <div class="name">Man. United<span class="record">13 pts</span></div>,
 <div class="name">Bournemouth<span class="record">16 pts</span></div>,
 <div class="name">Leicester City<span class="record">12 pts</span></div>,
 <div class="name">Wolverhampton<span class="record">15 pts</span></div>,
 <div class="name">Watford<span class="record">13 pts</span></div>,
 <div class="name">Everton<span class="record">12 pts</span></div>,
 <div class="name">West Ham<span class="record">7 pts</span></div>,
 <div class="name">Crystal Palace<span class="record">7 pts</span></div>,
 <div class="name">Brighton<span class="record">8 pts</span></div>,
 <div class="name">Southampton<span class="record">5 pts</span></div>,
 <div class="name">Newcastle<span class="record">2 pts</span></div>,
 <div class="name">Burnley<span class="record">8 pts</span></div>,
 <div class="name">Fulham<span class="record">5 pts</span></div>,
 <div class="name">Huddersfield<span class="record">3 pts</span></div>,
 <div class="name">Cardiff City<span class="record">2 pts</span></div>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i just answer your another question, BTW you can do something like this....

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get('https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/soccer-predictions/premier-league/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find_all('table', attrs={'class':'forecast-table'})
for i in table:
    tr = i.find_all('tr')
    for x in tr:
        try:
            name = x.find('div', attrs={'class':'name'})
            pts = x.find('span', attrs={'class':'record'})
            print('Name:', name.next, 'Pts:', pts.next)
        except:
            pass
```

Output:

```
Name: Man. City Pts: 19 pts
Name: Liverpool Pts: 19 pts
Name: Chelsea Pts: 20 pts
Name: Tottenham Pts: 18 pts
Name: Arsenal Pts: 18 pts
Name: Man. United Pts: 13 pts
Name: Bournemouth Pts: 16 pts
Name: Leicester City Pts: 12 pts
Name: Wolverhampton Pts: 15 pts
Name: Watford Pts: 13 pts
Name: Everton Pts: 12 pts
Name: West Ham Pts: 7 pts
Name: Crystal Palace Pts: 7 pts
Name: Brighton Pts: 8 pts
Name: Southampton Pts: 5 pts
Name: Newcastle Pts: 2 pts
Name: Fulham Pts: 5 pts
Name: Burnley Pts: 8 pts
Name: Huddersfield Pts: 3 pts
Name: Cardiff City Pts: 2 pts
```

Comment: Yes you did, thanks for that. But this doesn't answer my question, which is getting the teams and the points in different lists/columns

Comment: "next" is the function I was looking for! Thanks for this, you gave me a very good guidance.

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can seperate points and team names like this:

```
teams = []
s = bs(html)
for i in s.findAll("div"):
    teams.append(''.join(i.text))

point = []
name = []

for team in teams:
    count = 0
    for char in team:
        if (ord(char) >= 48) & (ord(char) <= 59):
            point.append(team[count:])
            name.append(team[:count])
            break
        count = count + 1

print(point)
print(name)
```

For the **Outputs**, it looks like this:

['19 pts', '19 pts', '17 pts', '18 pts', '18 pts', '13 pts', '16 pts', '12 pts', '15 pts', '13 pts', '12 pts', '7 pts', '7 pts', '8 pts', '5 pts', '2 pts', '8 pts', '5 pts', '3 pts', '2 pts']

['Man. City', 'Liverpool', 'Chelsea', 'Tottenham', 'Arsenal', 'Man. United', 'Bournemouth', 'Leicester City', 'Wolverhampton', 'Watford', 'Everton', 'West Ham', 'Crystal Palace', 'Brighton', 'Southampton', 'Newcastle', 'Burnley', 'Fulham', 'Huddersfield', 'Cardiff City']

Comment: Why did you canceled voting? Isn't this the format you wanted?